# Откуда здесь "не" взялось?

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано

Кликал-кликал на интересные вопросы и ответы -- насобирал на значок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажимаю на него и вижу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Откуда здесь "не" взялось вообще? Оно лишнее тут -- нужно убрать. Возможно, тут подразумевался некий список всех тех, кто НЕ заработал на этот знак -- но никакого списка сейчас там нет.

Answer (score 0):

Скажите, актуальна ли проблема? Возможно, информация на странице просто не успела обновиться, и поэтому вам был показан этот статус.

Comment: Вот не знаю, у меня это знак уже есть и я воспроизвести уже не смогу. Но это кажется на любом знаке воспроизводится, т.к. я на одном увидел проблему, а другой уже скриншотил ошибку.

Comment: @AK понятно. Тогда все просто: система не успела синхронизировать данные столь же быстро, как вы открыли информационную страницу значка.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5431/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-did-not-earn-this-badge